# python: alias for relative import

Tags: python, python-import

**Is it possible to import a module of the same package with an alias using relative import?**

Say I have the following package structure:

```
lib/
    foobar/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

And in foo.py, I'd like to use something from bar.py, but I'd like to use it as "bar.my_function", so instead of `from .bar import my_function`, I've tried `import .bar as bar` and `import .bar`, both of which don't work (invalid syntax exception). I've tried both pythhon2.7 and python3.4 (the latter being my target version).

However, what DOES work, and what I'm using now, is `import foobar.bar as bar`, i.e. absolute import instead of relative. It's an OK solution, given I don't expect the package name to change (and even if it does, there's not much to change in the code), but it would be nice if I could accomplish this using relative import!

Summary:

```
#import .bar as bar # why not?!?
#import .bar # shot in the dark
import foobar.bar as bar # current solution
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use

```
from . import bar
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) states concerning this

> [...] you can write explicit relative imports with the `from module import name` form of import statement. These explicit relative imports use leading dots to indicate the current and parent packages involved in the relative import. [...]

Comment: Of course, should've realized that myself! *facepalm* But well, hindsight's easier than foresight. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The new syntax also lets you apply an alias to the relatively-imported module, if you wish (e.g. if the module itself has a long-ish name).  `from . import long_module_name as bar`  (I spent a LONG time searching questions and documentation figuring that one out!).  It's a little klunky compared to Python 2 when the implicit relative import let you just do `import long_module_name as bar`, but at least it's still available as an option.